# Why does Gothic hūhjan have long ū?

Tags: germanic-languages, gothic

Why does Gothic hūhjan (which is cognate with hiuhma, hauhs)  have long ū?

Comment: Good question. If the forms in the conjugation table on Wiktionary are anything to go by, the long _ū_ must be quite recent and secondary, since the _-jan_ suffix takes the form associated with light stems (e.g., _hūhjis_ instead of _hūheis_. Is it certain that it _does_ have a the long vowel? The [linking article for the transliterated form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huhjan#Gothic) has a short _u_, and if [Proto-Finnic _kuhja_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Finnic/kuhja) is indeed from this word, that also suggests a short vowel.